# The trace of $F|K$ is non degenerate if and only if the trace of $E\otimes_{K}F|E$ is nondegenerate

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, trace, bilinear-form

Let $F|K$ be a finite field extension. I want to prove that if   $E|K$ is an algebraic extension, then the bilinear form
$$
F\times F\rightarrow K, (x,y)\mapsto Tr_{F|K}(xy)
$$ 
is nondegenerate if and only if 
$$
E\otimes_{K} F\times E\otimes_{K} F\rightarrow E, (x,y)\mapsto Tr_{E\otimes_{K}F|E}(xy)
$$
is nondegenerate.

I don't know where to start from.

Comment: Hm. Are you sure you mean $Tr_{E\otimes_KF\mid K}$?

Comment: My answer is about $Tr_{E\otimes_KF\mid E}$. If the characteristic of $K$ is zero, for example, the trace form over $K$ of $E\otimes_KF$ is nondegenerate iff $E\otimes_KF$ is a semisimple $K$-algebra, and your hypotheses are not enough to guarantee that.

Comment: the usualone, if the first is made up of elements $f_i$, the second one is just the one made up with the corresponding $1\otimes f_i$.

Comment: I suggest that you try to prove that $\{1\otimes f_i\}$ **is** a basis of $E\otimes_KF$ as an $E$-vector space. That $\{f_i\}$ is not a basis of $F$ as an $E$-vector space has nothing to do with this (and in fact does not even make sense, as $F$ is not an $E$-vector space in any sensible way :-) )

Comment: The $L$ is probably a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-degeneracy of a bilinear form is equivalent to having the matrix of the form with respect to a basis have non-zero determinant.

Show that your two bilinear forms have matrices with respect to appropriate bases of their underlying vector spaces which have the *same* determinant — in fact, the two matrices can be chosed to be the same matrix!